# SQLAlchemy with_polymorphic use string or table name instead of Class

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

To avoid circular imports, I cannot import the class to pass to `with_polymorphic`.

Is there a way to pass the table name or the string to `with_polymorphic` instead?
Eg. `with_polymorphic("User", "*")`

This is possible for relationships: `relationship("User")`